# Ruby 文字列型配列の重複した文字列の最小文字列のみを抽出するには？

Tags: ruby

Rubyで文字列型の配列の中身を、重複した文字列の最小文字列のみを抽出する方法がないか調べております。

`strArray = ["dir/a/00", "dir/a/01", "dir/a/02", "dir/a", "dir/b/00", "dir/b/01",  "dir/b/01/abc", "dir/b/01/abc/def", "dir/b/02", "dir/b"]`

このような文字列型配列があったときに、Array#uniqを使って以下の配列のように中身を削除する方法はありますでしょうか？(Array#uniqにこだわる必要はないのですが、速度が出せる書き方を教えて下さい。)

`strArray = ["dir/a", "dir/b"]`

どういうことかと言いますと、各配列要素の中身が要素の最小で一致している場合は、配列を要素の最小のみにしたいです。(比較対象は配列要素と配列要素、配列要素の中身のパスの最小ではないです。)

`"dir/a/00"は"dir/a"と比較した時に、"dir/a" + αの形になっているため削除したいです。

(要素の最小というのは、ほかの要素と比較した時に一番小さい単位と言えば伝わりますでしょうか？)`

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ご質問には正規表現が登場しませんが、正規表現を使って解決したいのですか？ファイルパスの配列から重複を除去できれば方法は問わないのでしょうか。 / また、パスの階層の深さは異なる可能性があるのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問の内容が伝わりづらくすみません。質問の内容を少し変更しました。

Comment: 最少パスは `"dir"` 1つではないのでしょうか? `"dir/a"` と `"dir/b"` が残るロジックにもう少し説明が欲しいです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問内容を変更しました。これで伝わりますでしょうか？

Comment: 具体的に、たとえば `"dir/a/00"` がどうして削除されるのかのロジックを解説していただけると分かりやすいのではないかと思いました。まだ私もどうして `"dir/a"` と `"dir/b"` が比較されないのか分かっていません。ディレクトリ木構造の各連結成分の根を求めたいわけではないのですよね？

Comment: [dir/a, dir/a/01] では dir/a が dir/a/01 も含むので [dir/a] だけにまとめることができますが、[dir/a, dir/b] では指定外の dir/c が存在するかもしれないので [dir] だけにまとめることはできない、ということかと。globパターンの配列から重複するものを取り除くとでも言いましょうか。

Comment: 皆様コメントありがとうございます。こういう場での質問は初めてでして、どういう言葉を使えば一般的に伝わりやすいかがわかりません。。。日本語力のなさを感じます。質問内容のほうは少し修正しました。これで伝わるとありがたいです。

Comment: 数字で表された名前は特別扱いするということですか？ @unarist さんの意見では、[dir/a, dir/a/01] の dir/a/01 についても、指定外の dir/a/02 が存在するかもしれないので dir/a だけにまとめることはできないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu `dir/a` はディレクトリ単位での指定、つまりは `dir/a/**`と同義なのだと思います。（globパターンという表現は適切ではなかったです）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

多分こういうことですよね？

```
str = ["dir/a/00", "dir/a/01", "dir/a/02", "dir/a", "dir/b/00", "dir/b/01",  "dir/b/01/abc", "dir/b/01/abc/def", "dir/b/02", "dir/b"]
ss = str.sort
p ss.reduce([ss.shift]) {|m,i| i.start_with?(m.last+"/") ? m : m << i}
```

文字列の配列として普通にソートしておき、重複しないパターンだけ抽出する、という流れで書いてみました。ディレクトリ名の一部やファイル名にマッチしないように、重複判定では `/` を付加しています。

速くはないと思いますが、一例として。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その通りでございます。
データも問題なく、今までと同じものが出力されました。
速度も自分が書いたアルゴリズムよりも速かったので、助かりました。
本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: @user20480 既存の実装があるのであれば、それを示すと処理内容が伝わりやすかったように思います。日本語で簡潔に説明するというのは難しいこともあるので、「これと同じ動きをするものを」とコードで示すのが確実です。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。次から既存の実装がある場合は、そのコードを掲載するようにします。ありがとうございました。